# Pentaho Mongo $maxScan weird behaviour

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I am having problems while using Penthao $maxScan option. The query is as followed

```
{ $query : { "_id" : { $gte : {'$oid':"543d0f7402a697a69aba94ce"} } }, $maxScan : 50 }
```

This displays 50 results as expected no problems, but when I increase the number greater than 100 i.e.

```
{ $query : { "_id" : { $gte : {'$oid':"543d0f7402a697a69aba94ce"} } }, $maxScan : 101 }
```

This displays 204 rows which is the total number of records in my collection. Any pointers to what's happening here ? I also tried the $limit keyword but its also not working !

Comment: $maxscan is NOT limit, it does something quite different, you are using the wrong fuction for the job

Comment: Understood. I also used $limit in PDI MongoInput step, this is not working too. If you could please guide me how can I extract chunk of data from mongo collection using Pentaho Data Integration Tool, I would really appreciate this?

Comment: There is currently no replacement for limit() using meta operators